# their is a crucial and big error in flask AttributeError: 'LargeBinary' object has no attribute 'output'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am programing a API in Flask (Python) and running it on colab
This error is about a object that I did not use and also says that I used its unknown attribute
this happens to all of my methods it via tested with postman

```
#Imports 
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse, abort, fields, marshal_with
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok

#Basic Application Inits
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
run_with_ngrok(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

#Database Models
class VideoModel(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    dish = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    NumberOfIngridents = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    Ingridents = db.Column(db.PickleType, nullable=False)
    VideoLink = db.Column(db.String(99999999999999), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self,dish,NumberOfIngridents,Ingridents,VideoLink):
        return f"Recipes(dish = {dish}, NumberOfIngridents = {NumberOfIngridents}, Ingridents = {Ingridents}, VideoLink = {VideoLink})"

video_put_args = reqparse.RequestParser()
video_put_args.add_argument("dish", type=str, help="Name of the dish is required", required=True)
video_put_args.add_argument("NumberOfIngridents", type=str, help="number of Ingridents is required", required=True)
video_put_args.add_argument("Ingridents", type=str, help="Ingridents of the dish is required", required=True)
video_put_args.add_argument("VideoLink", type=str, help="youtube VideoLink is required", required=True)


video_update_args = reqparse.RequestParser()
video_update_args.add_argument("dish", type=str, help="Name of the dish is required")
video_update_args.add_argument("NumberOfIngridents", type=str, help="number of Ingridents is required")
video_update_args.add_argument("Ingridents", type=str, help="Ingridents of the dish is required")
video_update_args.add_argument("VideoLink", type=str, help="youtube VideoLink is required")


#Dictionaries
resource_fields = {
    'id': fields.Integer,
    'dish': fields.String,
    'NumberOfIngridents': fields.Integer,
    'Ingridents':db.PickleType,
    'VideoLink':fields.String
}

db.create_all()
class Recipe(Resource):
    @marshal_with(resource_fields)
    def get(self, id):
        result = VideoModel.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
        if not result:
            abort(404, message="Could not find Dish with that id")
        return result

    @marshal_with(resource_fields)
    def put(self, id):
        args = video_put_args.parse_args()
        result = VideoModel.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
        if result:
            abort(409, message="Dish id taken...")

        Recipes = VideoModel(id=id, dish=args['dish'], NumberOfIngridents=args['NumberOfIngridents'], Ingridents=args['Ingridents'], VideoLink=args['VideoLink'])
        db.session.add(Recipes)
        return Recipes, 201
    db.session.commit()

    @marshal_with(resource_fields)
    def patch(self, id):
        args = video_update_args.parse_args()
        result = VideoModel.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
        if not result:
            abort(404, message="Dish doesn't exist, cannot update")

        if args['dish']:
            result.name = args['dish']
        if args['NumberOfIngridents']:
            result.userName = args['NumberOfIngridents']
        if args['Ingridents']:
            result.name = args['Ingridents']
        if args['VideoLink']:
            result.userName = args['VideoLink']

        return result
    db.session.commit()



    def delete(self, id, Recipes):
        del Recipes[id]
        return '', 204


api.add_resource(Recipe, '/<int:id>')

if __name__ == "__main__":
 app.run()
```

Above I have provide my main.py file and the error below

```
[2021-12-29 17:02:00,195] ERROR in app: Exception on /1 [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 467, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask/views.py", line 89, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 582, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 679, in wrapper
    return marshal(resp, self.fields, self.envelope)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 635, in marshal
    return OrderedDict([(envelope, OrderedDict(items))]) if envelope else OrderedDict(items)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 634, in <genexpr>
    for k, v in fields.items())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/type_api.py", line 1313, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.impl, key)
AttributeError: 'LargeBinary' object has no attribute 'output'
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Dec/2021 17:02:00] "GET /1 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is on the line indicated below:

```py
resource_fields = {
    'id': fields.Integer,
    'dish': fields.String,
    'NumberOfIngridents': fields.Integer,
    'Ingridents':db.PickleType,            ### error on this line
    'VideoLink':fields.String
}
```

Note that all the other values in this `resource_fields` dict are of the form `fields.Something`?  You're passing the wrong type of value here.

According to the [SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.PickleType), a `db.PickleType` uses a `LargeBinary` as the default implementation. This explains the occurrence of `LargeBinary` in the error message.  Also, if you look at the [Flask-RESTful documentation for fields](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#module-fields), you'll see all of the field classes have an `output` method.  It seems Flask is expecting the values within `resource_fields` to be fields, so it can call the `output` method of these fields, but you've given it something else that doesn't have an `output` method.

Of the various types of field available, I would guess that `fields.Raw` would be the most suitable one to use for this column.  Perhaps you went through the list yourself, concluded that none of them really fit and put the database type instead, as you didn't know what else to put in?  Anyway, try replacing the errant line with

```py
    'Ingridents': fields.Raw,
```

Disclaimer: I've never worked with Flask nor SQLAlchemy before and have not tested this.  There may also be other problems in your code which are not apparent because this error has prevented the errant part of your code from being reached.